# Google Cardboard SDK demo head tracking inversed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I upgraded my new Google Cardboard Unity game to the newer SDK, but now the head tracking is inversed:

The camera is upside down. Even the demo scene is the same way.

Has anyone been having the same issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in v0.4.10.  You can work around it in a few different ways:

- Turn off Native Distortion Correction
- Go back to v0.4.9
- Use Unity 5

Comment: Well, it fixed it temporarily, but now I'm getting a different issue. When restarting the game using Application.LoadLevel(0); the head tracking is again inversed. When starting the game the first time, it does not look like the proper interface.

Comment: Which of the 3 suggestions did you try?

Comment: the first one, and it worked well for my previous game.

Comment: Ok, so the value may be getting reset on a level load.  Can you say how you disabled the setting?

Comment: it took way too long, but I figured it out. some objects weren't being deleted in the scene, were interfering with the game